# HIPAA Related question regarding Prescription Rx Reports

Tags: hipaa

This is a close approximation of my in-person conversation at the Local CVS:

Me: Hi, I'd like to get the 2015 Medication Report for myself and my wife.

Clerk: I can print yours, if you have Photo ID, but not your wife's

Me: So she has to come in personally ?

Clerk: Yes with ID.

Me: So how come I can come in here and pick up her prescriptions with only giving you her Date of Birth, but I cannot get a printout of those same items?

Clerk: The report is personal health information but the medicine itself is not.

Does that make any sense whatsoever ?

Comment: No, it makes no sense, but it may well be following the legal requirements to the letter. This is probably not a good fit for this site though - it's essentially down to local laws, rather than information security. Might get a more useful answer from law.se.

Comment: law.se is a domain that is apparently for sale. There is no content except for a link to a bid site for domains.

Comment: @FredDeutsch Welcome to the Stack Exchange network. When users mention a `.se` site here, they are usually referring to a site on the `.stackexchange.com` domain. In this case, please see https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ohh - my bad, my niece lives in Sweden so when I saw a TLD of .se, it was automatic. Thanks